# Circle animation along SVG <path> element with D3.js with star and end position

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to move a circle on a path, from a start position to a final position

```
marker.transition().duration(1000).attrTween("transform", translateAlong_new(path.node(), startPoint, endPoint));

 function translateAlong_new(path, startPoint, endPoint) {
                var l = endPoint.longitud - 24;
        console.log("l",l,"icinio",startPoint,"fin",endPoint);

        return function() {
            return function(t) {
                                console.log(t);
                if (startPoint[0]>endPoint[0]) 
                                        var p = path.getPointAtLength((1-t) * l);//code
                else
                    var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
                var centerX = p.x, centerY = p.y - 100;

                return "translate(" + centerX + "," + centerY + ")";

            }
        }

    }
```

But i can not set star position.
Any idea?

Comment: Your question is not answerable in its current form.  What sort of values do `startPoint` and `endPoint` hold?  Set up a complete code snippet.

Comment: startPoint=path.getPointAtLength(0)